# java.util.ArrayList default capacity?

Tags: java, collections

As [per the Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList--) the default capacity for a java.util.ArrayList is 10.

> ```
> public ArrayList()
> ```
>
> Constructs an empty list with an initial capacity of ten.

I created a list without specifying the initial capacity as below and found that the initial capacity is 0 for the list.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> list50 = new ArrayList<String>(50);
list.add("1");
list50.add("2");
System.out.println(list.size());
```

[image: List without initial capacity]
[image: List with initial capacity specified]

I know i am making some silly mistake in interpretation, please correct me.

Comment: size != capacity

Comment: The explanation is right there in your question in the javadoc of ``DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA``: "how much to inflate when first element is added"

Comment: @bradimus OP is indeed right that the capacity is initially 0. `elementData` is an array of size 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initial capacity of a newly instantiated `ArrayList` is 0 - for performance reasons, an empty `ArrayList` uses a shared default array of size 0, so that if no new items are added to the list, you don't pay for allocating a new array that is never used.

Once the first item is added, the `DEFAULT_CAPACITY` (which is 10) is then used, i.e. the `ArrayList` creates a new array with size 10, which will then hold the first item (and has 9 additional, empty slots).

So I think you indeed used a slightly mistaken interpretation of the documentation.

The initial capacity is 0, and is then increased to 10 upon adding the first item, in order to avoid immediate reallocation for adding the next subsequent 9 items.

Comment: ArrayList al = new ArrayList(); [Size:  0, Capacity:  0]
ArrayList al = new ArrayList(5); [Size:  0, Capacity:  5]
ArrayList al = new ArrayList(new ArrayList(5)); [Size:  0, Capacity:  0]
al.add( "shailesh" );  [Size:  1, Capacity: 10]

Answer (score 1):

size and capacity are not the same...
every time you call add, ArrayList invoke **ensureCapacityInternal**, there you can find DEFAULT_CAPACITY which is 10 as you pointed....

```
private void ensureCapacityInternal(int minCapacity) {
    if (elementData == DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA) {
        minCapacity = Math.max(DEFAULT_CAPACITY, minCapacity);
    }

    ensureExplicitCapacity(minCapacity);
}
```

so this statement

```
minCapacity = Math.max(DEFAULT_CAPACITY, minCapacity);
```

increase the capacity to 10 after the 1st insertion